# How to run a Scala program via cron?

Tags: linux, scala, cron

I wrote a small Scala application. I have 2 classes in one source file including the App trait runner to start the program. It works just fine when I run it in the terminal:

```
scalac update.scala // compiling
scala update // run it
```

Now I want to run it with a cron job. For this I edited sudo crontab -e and added this:

```
*/2 * * * * scala /usr/bin/local/update
```

and made the script executable but nothing happend so far. I'm not sure how to do it: 
Do I have to make a jar file for this?
Do I have to add this before my classes or not?

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala -savecompiled $0 $@
!#
```

Does anyone have some experience with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect scala isn't in $PATH where cron can see it.

Try the following in a shell session:

```
$ which scala
```

Which should output something like "/opt/scala/2.9.1/bin/scala" or something. Could be in /usr/local, any number of places - java and the unix filesystem don't really play together nicely.

So now you have two options:

- Put the folder where scala lives in the system path (This will usually involve editing /etc/profile, but you don't specify the OS so I can't say for sure)
- (Easier) Just change the the cron entry to call /full/path/to/scala rather than just "scala"

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu. 'which scala' outputs /usr/bin/scala. I tried cron with the full path but the script won't run.

Comment: What happens if you run `/usr/bin/scala /usr/local/bin/update` in a console?

Comment: The cursor is blinking but nothing else is happening. I need to press CTRL+C to get back to the terminal.

Comment: I dunno then. Something must be really wonky in your cron setup, which, frankly, being ubuntu doesn't really surprise me.

Comment: Maybe it was an issue with Scala 2.9.0.1. I updated to Scala 2.9.1.final and it worked. Unfortunately my "notify-send" does not work. I use scala.sys.process._ for this. Any idea why? In the terminal everything is just fine...

Comment: @user1243091 - I must be missing something obvious with my answer. What is `/usr/bin/local/update` on your system?

Answer (score 2):

The `scala` command expects *the name of a compiled runnable object* or *a file containing a scala script source* (or a runnable jar file) as the thing to run.

If you have in update.scala `object update extends App` (and no package declaration) then after `scalac update.scala` (which should have produced a bunch of *.class files) `scala update` is the right thing to run.

If the produced class files are not in the current directory then the -classpath option should be used to tell scala where to find them, as in eg. `scala -classpath /usr/bin/local update`, if the class files are indeed in /usr/bin/local.

Saying `scala /usr/bin/local/update` would make sense if the file /usr/bin/local/update (this exact name) contained scala script source (that is more or less a sequence of scala expressions not wrapped in a class or object).